# Evaluating $\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} \, \text{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to find,
$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\,\text{d}x.$$
I tried substituting 
$$u = 1 - \cos (x)$$
or
$$u = \cos(x)$$
and even rewriting
$$\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$$
But neither works.

How should I bite it?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{1 - \cos x} = \frac{(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)}{1 - \cos x}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\cos x}=1+\cos x$$